# Intermittent Clunking noise from A/C Blower Fan

Tags: hvac

Three days ago my Central A/C was not working - came home from work and house was at 80 degrees.  Quick inspect of outdoor compressor showed all copper piping was covered in ice and frost.  Quick inspect of the air hanlder in the attic showed Coils covered in snow. I turned off the AC, let all the ice melt and  turned it back on, and the system ran fine but the blower would come on and off intermittently.

I turned AC off before I left for work the next day.  That evening, I turned the system on and my wife said she heard Clunking and Rumbling noises in the attic.  I pulled the front panel off the air handler and started the AC again and could see it was the Blower fan.  When the blower came up to full speed, it started making clunking noises like a pair of sneakers in the dryer and stopped.  And started again.

Since the I've been "cautiously" running the system and the noise hasn't come back and the system hasn't iced up again.  House is comfortable. Last night I checked inlet air temperature (74 degrees) and what was coming out of the registers (57 degrees) so the delta is 17 degrees.

Local HVAC service came by two days ago.  The tech said he thought the [expansion?] valve "might be" faulty.  He also said that since I have an R-22 system, no one will work on those anymore and I have to replace my entire system end-to-end and it's going to cost between $6,000 and $8,000 dollars.

Bottom Line: (a) The blower fan is making noise and shuts down intermittently - and (b) the system iced up three days ago.

Here's my question:  isn't it more likely the intermittent blower fan is interrupting air flow over the coils causing the system to ice up - and not the other way around?  Especially since the blower fan made the clunking and rumbling noises a few times two nights ago when there was no ice on the coils.

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.  If I had to suffer temperature extremes one way or the other, I'd much rather freeze to death than swelter in the heat.  Thanks in advance

Comment: When a rotating unit(fan) makes noise it is usually a bad bearing.  Clunking sounds like the bearing is gone, instead for going.  I was lucky I had water when I lost a bearing baling hay.  Burnt/burning hay is not good.

Comment: Could be a bad blower motor mount.  A bad blower can cause the cols to freeze up.  Get in there and see if anything's loose.